Placing images and environment side by side
I am working on a document using ConTeXt that need to have page layout similar to the picture

The pictures illustrate steps that are provided in the itemized environment.
How could be approach it? I looked into columnsets, placesidebyside, looked into layers and absolute positioning. How could I split the page for small pictures column and itemized environment ? Should I use columnsets, floats, or something else ?
It's also a multi-page document and I each page is structured in a similar yet different way, e.g. big picture could be at the bottom and it could be 2, 3 or 4 pictures illustrating the steps.
Note, that unlike Text and figure side by side in a list in ConTeXt number of pictures and items in itemized environment does not have to be the same.

Maybe side floats or combinations?

@MaxChernoff Maybe and. (Not by computer, so cannot test.)

How do you want it to look if text is longer than images? Opposite? Should the images have a certain width? As it is now there is a big risk one will give an answer that does not fit your needs.

The second version of it is what I wanted

I still think that you should update the question with more information (requested in comment), but following the suggestion of @MaxChernoff (with and instead of or), to use a side float where we put the images in a combination, might be working for you.
\setupexternalfigures
  [location=default]

\starttext

\samplefile{knuthmath}

\startplacefloat
  [figure]
  [location={left,nonumber}]
  \startcombination
    [nx=1,
     ny=3,
     after={\blank[big]}]
    {\externalfigure[cow][width=4cm]}{}
    {\externalfigure[cow][width=4cm]}{}
    {\externalfigure[cow][width=4cm]}{}
  \stopcombination
\stopplacefloat

\blank[enable]

\startitemize[n]
  \startitem
    \samplefile{knuthmath}
  \stopitem
  \startitem
    \samplefile{ward}
  \stopitem
  \startitem
    \samplefile{knuthmath}
  \stopitem
  \startitem
    \samplefile{ward}
  \stopitem
\stopitemize

\samplefile{knuthmath}

\stoptext

This gives

As you see, it will not be even with the cows and the last item. The cure is already there. If we change after={\blank[big]} into after={\blank[3*big]} we get the following output:

Now the sizes match. As a final comment, the \blank[enable] enables the white space that by default is disabled for side floats (try without it).

That looks awesome! The second version of it is what I wanted. Of course there's some tinkering involved to make sure that the text and column of pictures are "approximately the same" heights

One thing, though, i looks like I have to manually adjust n in after={\blank[n*big]} based on the text in the items. If it's too much text then it flows under. Is there a way to prevent that  by having blanks just after the float ?

This is the kind of information that would be handy to have in the question. Now you were quick to accept this answer, so I suggest that you ask a new question, where you specify the new problem that was not explained in this question.
